# Kendo CheckboxList stores the name of its DataSource as the control value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

My CSHTML file defines the following control:

```
@Html.CheckBoxList("PriorDeviceUse").DataSource(ViewBag.PriorDeviceUse as System.Data.DataTable).Value(Model.PriorDeviceUse).ColumnLayout(1).ColumnLayoutCSS(new string[] { "column-width-99", "column-width-104", "column-width-85" })
```

My Controller uses these methods:

```
public ActionResult PrePriorLiving(PrePriorLiving objPrePriorLiving)
{
    objPrePriorLiving = this.LoadData(objPrePriorLiving);
    return View(base.GetViewPath("PrePriorLiving"), objPrePriorLiving);
}

private PrePriorLiving LoadData(PrePriorLiving objPrePriorLiving)
{
    PrePriorLivingBLL objPrePriorLivingBLL = new PrePriorLivingBLL();

    //Loads the actual record from the DB
    objPrePriorLiving = objPrePriorLivingBLL.GetPriorLivingInfo(objPrePriorLiving);

    //Populates ViewBag with dropdown values
    FillDropdown(objPrePriorLiving);

    return objPrePriorLiving;
}

private void FillDropdown(PrePriorLiving objPrePriorLiving)
{
    PickListBLL objPickListBLL = new PickListBLL();         
    Category objCategory = new Category();

    objCategory.CategoryName = "PriorDeviceUse";
    ViewBag.PriorDeviceUse = objPickListBLL.MasterPickList(objCategory);
    //MasterPickList method just returns a data table populated via a stored procedure which relies on the CategoryName string
}

public DataTable MasterPickList(Category objCategory)
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_GET_PickListLookup"))
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aCategory", objCategory.CategoryName);
        return DataHelper.mGetDataTable(sqlCommand, "PickList", base.PRO_FacilityKey);
    }
}


public static DataTable mGetDataTable(SqlCommand sqlCommand, string dataSetName, string key)
{
    DataSet dsData = new DataSet(dataSetName);

    sqlCommand.CommandType = (DataHelper.GetCommandType(sqlCommand)).CommandType;

    DbCommand dbCommand = (DbCommand)sqlCommand;
    dbCommand.CommandTimeout = AppConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;

    Database database = DataHelper.mGetDatabase(key);
    database.LoadDataSet(dbCommand, dsData, dataSetName);

    return dsData.Tables[0];
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on that `return` statement in the first method I posted, `objPrePriorLiving.PriorDeviceuse` (the field my view is bound to), the value is `null`. But as soon as the page loads, if I inspect the HTML the control has the value of the `DataSet`'s `Name` property (`"PickList"`) that was used during the population of the `ViewBag`. I cannot figure out how or why this is happening, and no where else in my code where we use a `CheckBoxList` does this happen, but I cannot discern what's being done differently here.

I've tried assigning the `DataSet` an empty string, and I tried changing `mGetDataTable` to simply use `DataSet dsData = new DataSet();` constructor instead -- in both cases, an exception is thrown:

> type="System.ArgumentException" message="Cannot change the name of the DataSet to an empty string."

So, what am I doing wrong with my CheckBoxList?

Comment: `@Html.CheckBoxList("PriorDeviceUse")` means that the method looks up (in order) `ModelState`, `ViewData` and the model property to determine the `value`. Since you have `ViewBag.PriorDeviceUse` (which is added to `ViewData`), it uses that value

Comment: Change the `ViewBag` name to something other that the property name

Comment: @StephenMuecke This seems to fix it, but I'm not sure I understand *why*. Like the `ViewBag.PriorDeviceUse` is a `DataTable`, so why does it just assume to use the `DataTable.Name` as its value?

Comment: Because all `HtmlHelper` call `.ToString()` to generate the the `value` attribute

Comment: Thanks. If you want to post this as an answer I can happily Accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HtmlHelper` methods determine the `value` attribute by checking in order

1. `ModelState`
2. `ViewData`
3. The value of the model property

In your case, your binding to a property named `PriorDeviceUse`, but you have also added a property of the same name to `ViewBag` (which gets added to the `ViewDataDictionary`).

The method therefore finds a value for `PriorDeviceUse` in `ViewData` and uses that value rather than the value of the model property.

Because `HtmlHelper` methods call `.ToString()` on the value, the name of your table is rendered as the `value` attribute.

Change the name of the `ViewBag` property to anything other than the name of your model property, and the `value` attribute will be correctly rendered.

Comment: Thanks again! I understand the 'order' to where the value comes from, now

Comment: I just noticed you have a parameter for  `PrePriorLiving` in your GET method, which means if that model contains a `PriorDeviceUse` property, then you are most likely using the value from `ModelState`. Its generally a bad idea to have parameters for models in GET methods - is there a reason you are doing that?